# Replacing custom bootloader with GRUB

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader, linux-kernel, arm

Context: I have a rooted device, one board Linux with busybox binary, and I would like to install new packages on it. Unfortunately busybox doesn't provide utilities for that, apart from rpm. To add to my woes the device has proprietary bootloader, that checks during boot for manufacturer signature.
Thankfully I have chroot, and can use it to load archlinux.

Actual question:
Suppose I want to get rid of the manufacturers bootloader and replace it with grub.

How would I do that?

I found an article: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

That seems to indicate it is possible, in theory. And with relatively few adjustments I could perform this process on my device. I just don't want to make some stupid mistake.

Comment: Depending on what kind of device you have this might or might not be possible or require any number of very specific steps. What device you actually looking at?

Comment: It's a Steam link. As I said I have root access, I can install rpms, manipulate filesystems, the whole deal.

Comment: While that is true, as you also said, the bootloader is something you can't easily touch. Just as an example it might do a signature check before it actually loads you kernel. Console devices have a history of having trust chains to load up verified code (and that usually breaks somewhere).

Comment: Yes it does check the signature. That's why I want to replace it.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I'm talking about. It could very well be that they're implementing a secure boot scheme. As such you would need remove actual hardware in order to use a "free" bootloader. Did you do research whenever that's the case or not? If it is and you just replace the bootloader the only thing you will get is a rather nice looking paperweight. Also if you know how to get into arch why not just setup a script that automates the process and leave the base system in place?`